# Can any connected graph of $\ge k$ nodes be partitioned into $k$ components?

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry

Dyer and Frieze in "ON THE COMPLEXITY OF PARTITIONING INTO CONNECTED SUBGRAPHS" showed that the problem of deciding whether a planar graph has a connected-$k$-partition is NP-complete.

On a graph with fewer than $k$ nodes, of course the partition is impossible. Cutting a graph with sufficient nodes into pieces strikes me as trivial. Is there a planar graph of $k$ or more nodes that can't be partitioned into $k$ subgraphs? When does Dyer and Frieze's problem result in a "no"?

Comment: Did Dyer and Frieze really publish a paper with the entire title in capital letters?

Comment: Well, Discrete Applied Mathematics 10 did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have misunderstood the paper's definition of a connected-$k$-partition. It's on the first page of [the paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2866/a0efccfaf7824ca602d481ce18c24aae4d28.pdf). It doesn't involve partitioning into $k$ parts but partioning into parts each of size $k$. Moreover, it requires the induced subgraphs to be connected. An example of a graph on $4$ vertices that has no connected-$2$-partition is the [star graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_%28graph_theory%29) $S_3$.

Comment: You're right; thanks for setting me straight. $|X_i|=k$, not $|p|=k$. I need to abandon the constraint on the size of the subgraphs. What is the proper name for partition into $k$  connected parts without regard for the size of the parts?

Comment: @AaronBrick: I don't know of any more specific name than that: partition into $k$ connected parts.